# Image is not getting loaded to an image tag on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have tried to load an image to an image tag by rails as follows. The path is correct .

```
 <%= image_tag("581efb2dcd752bacafda09c4deaba141b76693d1.jpg")%>
```

it renders as below and when I open it from the firebug it said image cannot be loaded . What can possibly go wrong here?

```
 <img src="/home/kalanamith/Documents/projects/test/private/documents/blackandwhite/581efb2dcd752bacafda09c4deaba141b76693d1.jpg">
```

Comment: Maybe because you specified absolute path while adding image. That's the very possible way how you get this link. But app tries to find it in your relative path of your application. RAILS_ROOT/public/home/kalanamith... etc.

Comment: I tried with the relative path as well , though it didnt work  /private/documents/blackandwhite/581efb2dcd752bacafda09c4deaba141b76693d1.jpg

Comment: have you tried for another image on the same path??

Comment: @Kalanamith, Take a look again, it will look for image in RAILS_ROOT/public/YOUR_PATH directory. you need to put it in public directory. try that.

Comment: well for the constraints i cannot put images in to any other folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really simple. You can specify where your rails will look for assets and add these directories.

in your environments files you can add

```
# development.rb for example
config.assets.paths << "/home/kalanamith/Documents/projects/test/private/documents/"
```

so 
`<%= image_tag("/blackandwhite/581efb2dcd752bacafda09c4deaba141b76693d1.jpg")%>` will work fine.

Comment: The fact is I cannot change the existing folder structure :)

Comment: oh, man, you dont have to. JUST ADD your path where all your images are in config.assets.path. The fact is if you'd try to do that you will already have result.